# Tiki Wiki Search Index Not Configured Correctly

Tags: tiki-wiki

I'm working on a Tiki Wiki and ran into this error today

[image: The Error]

I have tried disabling the search feature all together and still the error wont stop, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check your server directory permissions. Tiki requires write access to your **../temp/unified-index/** directory.

Answer (score 0):

What we had to do was actually set up a Cron Job that rebuilt the search index ever 10 minutes